# JFrame freezes without reason outside of IDE

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I have a Java application program that when I run it with my IDE (Netbeans) works fine. The application is a simple JFrame with a JScrollPane, JTextArea (as logger) and JButton to perform the main function. The problem is, when I "clean and build" the project and execute it outside from IDE, It freezes itself without reason when I click on the JButton. The JScrollPane change to indertemine mode when the programs runs, but it freezes in the middle!. I tried to execute with the console to see some Exception, but nothing happens.

**TestSwingThread.java**

```
package testswingthread;

public class TestSwingThread 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        DisplayWindow dw = new DisplayWindow();

        //FRAME PROPERTIES
        dw.setTitle("Test");
        dw.setResizable(false);
        dw.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        dw.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

**DisplayWindow.java**

```
package testswingthread;

public class DisplayWindow extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public DisplayWindow() 
    {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form. WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        mainActionButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        statusBar = new javax.swing.JProgressBar();
        jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        logger = new javax.swing.JTextArea();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jPanel1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Datos"));

        mainActionButton.setText("MainAction");
        mainActionButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                mainActionButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(mainActionButton)
                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(mainActionButton)
                .addGap(0, 54, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        logger.setEditable(false);
        logger.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(225, 224, 224));
        logger.setColumns(20);
        logger.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Courier New", 0, 15)); // NOI18N
        logger.setRows(5);
        logger.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Logger"));
        logger.setCaretColor(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jScrollPane2.setViewportView(logger);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 484, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(statusBar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 380, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(statusBar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 37, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGap(6, 6, 6))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void mainActionButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 

        Runnable e = new MainActionButtonActions(this);
        Thread process_e = new Thread(e);
        process_e.start();
    }                                                

    public void blockButtons()
    {
        mainActionButton.setEnabled(false);
    }

    public void unblockButtons()
    {
        mainActionButton.setEnabled(true);
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
    public javax.swing.JTextArea logger;
    private javax.swing.JButton mainActionButton;
    public javax.swing.JProgressBar statusBar;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

**MainActionButtonActions.java**

```
package testswingthread;

import javax.swing.JTextArea;


public class MainActionButtonActions implements Runnable
{
    private final JTextArea logger;
    private final DisplayWindow window;

    public MainActionButtonActions(DisplayWindow p_window)
    {
        window = p_window;
        logger = window.logger;
        logger.setText(null); //CLEAR THE LOG
    }

    public void run() 
    {
        exec();
    }

    public boolean exec()
    {
        boolean result = false;

        window.blockButtons();
        window.statusBar.setIndeterminate(true);

        appendToLogger("TRY ONE..");
        appendToLogger("TRY TWO..");
        appendToLogger("TRY THREE..");

        window.unblockButtons();
        window.statusBar.setIndeterminate(false);
        return result;
    }

    private void appendToLogger(String text)
    {
        logger.append("\n" + text);
        logger.setCaretPosition(logger.getDocument().getLength());
    } 

}
```

Regards!

Comment: You're modifying Swing components outside the event dispatch thread. Don't do that, **Swing is not thread safe**. Check the [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) tutorial for proper thread use.

Comment: I don't have this problem when I test the program with Netbeans, It works perfectly there.. must be something else

Comment: @kiheru is correct; fix that problem, and see what remains; if NetBeans obscures the problem, try the  command line; please edit your question to include a [complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exhibits any remaining problem.

Comment: @Nico just because your code runs in an IDE doesn't necessarily make it proper

Comment: @trashgod I have already tried with command line and nothing shows up. I think the example is complete. During the execution i have to write the logger to show where the program is to the user.

Comment: *"I think the example is complete."*  Think again.  A collection of uncompilable code snippets with no `main(String[])` method or imports is not 'complete'.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson, I added main method, but as I said, I think is not relevant.

Comment: *"I think is not relevant."*   It is still uncompilable code snippets.How the heck do you expect someone else to see the problem if the code does not even compile.  -1 because you seem to have skipped following the link added by @trashgod over 2 hours ago.  I've already voted to close this on the basis of 'lack of MCVE', now, I'll just wish you luck with it and bow out.  There are too many people need help to bother with this problem any further.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson, I read the link before..where the code is not compatible? I can not paste all the code, it is to big. I am writing right now a new program to reproduces the error but I can't, this new program works fine :( .

Comment: *"where the code is not compatible?"*  Compilable!=Compatible.  Ask yourself, 'Can someone copy paste that into their IDE, **compile it** as is, and run the code?'.  If not, it's not an MCVE of a run-time problem.  *"I am writing right now a new program to reproduces the error but I can't, this new program works fine"*  Now you might understand why I laughed out loud when you wrote *"I think is not relevant."*  You seem to have no idea what is relevant to the problem and what is not - that is one of the reasons we tend to demand an MCVE.  Unless you can make one, we have no chance of helping.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82544/discussion-between-nico-and-andrew-thompson).

Comment: Hello, @Andrew Thompson, see my edit. I could reproduces the problem with a smaller program. The whole code is posted now.